# Which part of MVVM i should be store data in database

Tags: android, android-mvvm

I just learn about MVVM and injection and i would like to know which part of this structure i should be store data in database

simple implementation of mvvm in kotlin is:

`QuotesActivity`

```
class QuotesActivity : AppCompatActivity(), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein by closestKodein()
    private val viewModelFactory: QuotesViewModelFactory by instance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quotes)
        initializeUi()
    }

    private fun initializeUi() {
        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
                .get(QuotesViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.getQuotes().observe(this, Observer { quotes ->
            ..
            textView_quotes.text = stringBuilder.toString()
        })

        // When button is clicked, instantiate a Quote and add it to DB through the ViewModel
        button_add_quote.setOnClickListener {
            ..
        }
    }
}
```

`QuotesViewModel`

```
class QuotesViewModel(private val quoteRepository: QuoteRepository)
    : ViewModel() {

    fun addQuote(quote: Quote) = quoteRepository.addQuote(quote)

    fun getQuotes() = quoteRepository.getQuotes()
}
```

`QuotesViewModelFactory` class

```
class QuotesViewModelFactory(private val quoteRepository: QuoteRepository)
    : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return QuotesViewModel(quoteRepository) as T
    }
}
```

`Database`

```
interface Database {
    val quoteDao: QuoteDao
}
```

`DatabaseFakeImpl`

```
class DatabaseFakeImpl : Database {
    override val quoteDao: QuoteDao = QuoteDaoFakeImpl()
}
```

`QuoteDao` interface

```
interface QuoteDao {
    fun addQuote(quote: Quote)
    fun getQuotes(): LiveData<List<Quote>>
}
```

`QuoteDaoFakeImpl` class:

```
class QuoteDaoFakeImpl : QuoteDao {
    private val quoteList = mutableListOf<Quote>()
    private val quotes = MutableLiveData<List<Quote>>()

    init {
        quotes.value = quoteList
    }

    override fun addQuote(quote: Quote) {
        quoteList.add(quote)
        quotes.value = quoteList
    }

    override fun getQuotes() = quotes as LiveData<List<Quote>>
}
```

`Quote` model class

```
data class Quote(val text: String, val author: String) {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$text - $author"
    }
}
```

`QuoteRepository`

```
interface QuoteRepository {
    fun addQuote(quote: Quote)
    fun getQuotes(): LiveData<List<Quote>>
}
```

`QuoteRepositoryImpl`

```
class QuoteRepositoryImpl(private val quoteDao: QuoteDao)
    : QuoteRepository {
    override fun addQuote(quote: Quote) {
        quoteDao.addQuote(quote)
    }

    override fun getQuotes() = quoteDao.getQuotes()
}
```

I think that should be implemented on `QuoteDaoFakeImpl` class such as simple `middleware` for example:

```
class QuoteDaoFakeImpl : QuoteDao {
    ...
    override fun addQuote(quote: Quote) {
        quoteList.add(quote)
        quotes.value = quoteList

        /* IN THIS PART OF CODE */
    }

    override fun getQuotes() = quotes as LiveData<List<Quote>>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it's the ViewModel. Since it's the layer that's responsible for retrieving and showing the data. It can also save and load it.

But even a better implementation would be to separate the database operations to a separate Logic layer where the data can be retrieved and saved before it is being pushed to the ViewModel.

Comment: thanks, could you show me how can i do it with my posted code?

Answer (score 0):

You should store data in Repository. It should Query and Insert into the data sources like Room.